# nUnit rowtest extension skips my tests

Tags: nunit, resharper, gallio

When I use the NUnitExtension.RowTest.dll it ignores my tests in Resharper/VS2008 and Gallio Icarus.   Does anyone have a config that works?

```
    [RowTest]
    [Row(5, 6, 11)]
    public void Should_Do_RowTest(int a, int b, int expected)
    {

        Assert.AreEqual(a+b, expected);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Clunkier I know, but how about?

```
[Test, Sequential]
public void Should_Do_RowTest(
    [Values(5,7)] int a, 
    [Values(6,9)] int b, 
    [Values(11,16)] int expected)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(a+b, expected);
}
```

You won't need the Extensions DLL with this code.  It will perform:

```
Should_Do_RowTest(5,6,11);
Should_Do_RowTest(7,9,16);
```